# why the javascript method is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, cordova

I dont understand why validate() the method is not working. when i run this nothing happens. 
I think there is a problem after $.ajax() method. i want to 
1)validate id and password fields if they are blank it prompts alert
2)then i want to validate whether the id and password matches the record in mysql database so because of that i used $.ajax method.

```
     function validate(){
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["T_id"].value;
        var y = document.forms["myForm"]["T_Password"].value;
                    var filter =/^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$/;
        if (!filter.test(x)) {
          alert('Please provide a valid email address');    
          return false;
         }
        if(true){
        var inputEmail=$('#T_id').val();
        var inputPassword=$('#T_Password').val();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ip:8080/SmartAttendanceSystem/loginUserRestService/getUserModel",
        data: "Email="+inputEmail+"& Password=" +inputPassword",                
                         success : function(data) {
                            alert("Uploaded! "+data)
                            window.location="photo.html"
                         },
                });
        }
        return( true );
        }
```

HTML CODE:

```
            <form action="" method="post" name="myForm">
            <input type="email" name="T_id" id="T_id" />
            <input type="password" id="pwd" name="T_Password" />
            <input type="button" value="Login" id="loginButton" onclick="validate();">
```

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting in your question and you will see the problem.

Comment: Also, learn about the same-origin policy.

Comment: You must learn elementary debugging techniques when writing any javascript.  You should not be coming here because a typo has made a javascript syntax error that the browser will surely point you at if you just look in the error console.

Comment: okay i didnt knew that there was a typing mistake otherwise i will not post it here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has error

```
data: "Email="+inputEmail+"& Password=" +inputPassword",
```

You have given a extra `"` after inputPassword.

Use browser's console or add-on like firebug to find Javascript errors.

Comment: okay thank you the problem is solved